# Is this proof that the algebraic numbers are countable legit?

Tags: real-analysis, logic

Here is my version of the proof that the set of algebraic numbers is countable. Is it correct?

First we show that the set of polynomials with rational coefficients is countable. For ever fixed natural $n$, there is a bijection between the set of polynomials of degree $n$ and the set $\mathbb Q^n$ that sends $x^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\dots+a_0$ to $(a_{n-1},\dots,a_0)$. Thus the set of polynomials with rational coefficients of a fixed degree is countable. The set of all polynomials with rational coefficients is the union of that set over all $n\in \mathbb N$, so it's also countable as a countable union of countable sets.

Now each polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $n$ roots. We can enumerate all polynomials due to the above: $p_1(x),p_2(x),\dots.$ Let $(P)_{i\in \mathbb N}$ be the set of all polynomials with rational coefficients.  Let $S_i$ be the set of all roots of $p_i(x)$. The set of all algebraic numbers is the union of $S_i$ over all $i\in \mathbb N$.  This is a countable union of finite sets, thus countable.

Comment: Seems good to me. You will have counted each algebraic number multiple times, but that's not really an issue.

Comment: @Arthur Hot to see that that isn't an issue? Maybe if I hadn't counted the same number multiple times, the set of algebraic numbers would end up to be finite?

Comment: Algebraic numbers include rational numbers, so theu are not finite...

Comment: @xarles I think that he was joking.  If countable is overcounting then the answer would be finite.

Comment: This proof is fine.